# como tipar dinamicamente um hook personalizado no react?

Tags: react, typescript, next.js

eu estou tentando tipar dinamicamente um hook personalizado, a minha ideia é que ele funcione da seguinte maneira:

```
 function RandomComponent() {
  //onde 'GenericType' seria a tipagem dinamica feita particularmente para esse componente
  const realtime = useRealtime<GenericType>()
}
```

atualmente o hook `useRealtime` está da seguinte maneira:

```
interface Props<T> {
  [key: string]: T 
}

export function useRealtime<T>() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState<Props<T>>();
}
```

apesar de não disparar nenhum erro, o problema surge ao utilizar `setItems` onde aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Type 'x' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'x'.
```

Como posso tipar dinamicamente o state `items` dentro do hook `useRealtime`?

Comment: Como está usando o `setItems`? Como é o tipo `GenericType`? Coloque o código completo do seu hook